# Using Vectors on image xcasset Xcode and Render as Template

Tags: ios, xcode, vector, xcasset

someone can give an example to use Vector image (.pdf) on Xcode with option Render: "as template" in the image.xcasset? 
Can I programatically set color of the vector image? if yes how?

Thanks,
Omar.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can. When using "as template", the system ignores the image’s color information and creates an image stencil based on the alpha values in the image (parts of the image with an alpha value of less than 1.0 get treated as completely transparent). This stencil can then be recolored using `tintColor` to match the rest of your user interface.

See [Apple documentation about template images in UIKitUICatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIView-SW7).

Comment: Thank you @Ludovic it's work in iOS8. 
A little bit tricky to work in iOS7 for images and buttons.